# When Launching search dialog the soft keyboard doesnt show magnifying glass

Tags: android

in my android app on launching **onSearchRequested();** to open a search dialog, but when  u user types a search in the "search dialog" - the softkeyboard shows an arrow icon (for Carriage return) to commence the search instead of a  magnifying glass

how can i show the magnifying glass instead - 
screenshot of the issue is attached

search configuration is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

[image]

Comment: Can u please post the design xml of the search box?

Comment: I didn't design the search box. i just call "onSearchRequested(" and android takes care of it.

if you mean - the xml configuration of the search it's:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Try This.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:hint="@string/search_hint"
                            android:label="@string/app_name"
                            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"></searchable>
```